# How to create/save this database special calculated field - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a `database field` called **sample_code**. This field is composed on the following way: `sample_id/year/lab_id`

The `lab_id` is fixed, always the same. The `year` changes accordingly to the current year... The `sample_id` its incremental (resetting every year and not a database field).

What I want to do is every-time I create a new sample it generates this `sample_code` for me and saves it along with the rest of the sample fields...

My doubts are: 
1 - How can I keep incrementing sample_id if it's not on the database?
2 - How can I reset the sample ID code each year?
3 - Where's the best place to put/call this code? Sample's controller?

Thanks for all the help you can give

Comment: Thanks Marc, for the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using your database outside of your app, it should be fine to just store the `sample_id` as its own column.  You can then put a method on your model that returns something like:

```
def sample_code
  "#{sample_id}/#{Time.now.year}/<lab_id>"
end
```

Then you can just increment `sample_id` each time.

**EDIT**

Since you need to reset the id to 1 each year and the model is called `Sample`, you should avoid confusion by calling it something like `annual_id` instead of `sample_id`.  `sample_id` would likely be confused with `sample.id`, which is a completely different thing.

With that change, you should just store the info in three columns on the model to make it easy: `annual_id`, `year`, and `lab_id`.  Then for each record you can set:

```
annual_id = Sample.where(year: Time.now.year).pluck(:annual_id).max.to_i + 1
year = Time.now.year
lab_id = <however you are defining this>
```

This will use the current year for `year` and then reset the `annual_id` to 1 when there are no records because the year has changed (new year will give `nil.to_i + 1 => 1`).

Then you can just return the format you want for any given data point:

```
def sample_code
  "#{annual_id}/#{year}/#{lab_id}"
end
```

Comment: I thought of that but then it won't "reset" the sample_id each year... For example, I will have 1/2013/1; then 2/2013/1, ... , and then in 2014, the first value would be (if 2013 ended in 33/2013/1) => 34/2014/1...

Comment: What's it supposed to be in the second year?  That should be easy to put in.

Comment: Imagine we have 10 samples in 2013, in lab 1, then the last one would be 10/13/1. The first one from 2014, in lab 1, would be: 1/14/1

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I put the annual_id, year and lab_id "definitions" on the controller, the "sample_code" method on the model, and then used some hidden fields on the views to set them. I don't know if this is the best way, but it worked, thanks a lot for your help!